# Unable to pass Unit Test getting : System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: trigger, unit-test

I have a **Apex trigger** which is :

```
trigger ProductRevenue on ProductStore__c (after update) {

    List<Revenue__C> newOpps = new List<Revenue__C>();

  for (ProductStore__c prodobj : Trigger.new) {

      Revenue__C revobj = new Revenue__c();
      if(prodobj.QuantitySold__c > 1)
      {
      revobj.Transaction__C = prodobj.QuantitySold__c + ' ' + prodobj.Name__c + 's' + ' ' + 'sold';
      }

      else
      {
       revobj.Transaction__C = prodobj.QuantitySold__c + ' ' + prodobj.Name__c + ' ' + 'sold';   
      }

      revobj.Revenue__c = (prodobj.QuantitySold__c)*(prodobj.Price__C);
      revobj.DateTime__C = datetime.now();
      revobj.ProductType__C = prodobj.Name__c;
      revobj.QuantitySold__C = prodobj.QuantitySold__c;



      newOpps.add(revobj);

  }
insert newOpps;

}
```

I have written a **Unit Test** for this :

```
@isTest
private class TestProductRevenue {

   static testMethod void Testing()

   {

       List<ProductStore__c> newlist = new List<ProductStore__c>();
       ProductStore__c obj = new ProductStore__C ();
       obj = [SELECT ProductStore__c.QuantitySold__C FROM ProductStore__c WHERE ProductStore__c.Name = 'AC'];
       obj.QuantitySold__C = 2;
       newlist.add(obj);

       Test.startTest();
       update newlist;
       Test.stopTest();

   }

}
```

On running the Test, the test fails showing error :

**System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject**

I am not finding any feasible solution to this. Any help will be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance ... !!!

Comment: You don't have visibility into org data in a test context. It's recommended to create test data to use inside of your test methods. This query - `[SELECT ProductStore__c.QuantitySold__C FROM ProductStore__c WHERE ProductStore__c.Name = 'AC']` won't return any rows, that's the source of your error.

Comment: ... i.e. insert the objects that your trigger will reference and that your test can then assert against. See e.g. [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests).

Comment: Thank you guys for clearing the concept. It helped me a lot ... !!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Haven't tested it.

```
@isTest
private class TestProductRevenue {

   static testMethod void Testing()
   {
       ProductStore__c obj = new ProductStore__C ();
       obj.QuantitySold__c = 5;
       obj.Name__c = 'Name' ;
       obj.Price__C = 101.23;   

       insert obj;

       obj.Price__C = 201.23;

       update obj;

       Revenue__C revobj = [SELECT Id,Revenue__c,DateTime__C,ProductType__C,QuantitySold__C FROM Revenue__C limit 1];

       System.assertEquals(revobj.ProductType__C,obj.Name__c);

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion it worked .... !!!!! :-) :-) :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any data in your test class in ProductStore__c  Object > You have to manually create it.
Something like

```
@isTest 
private class HelloWorldTestClass {
    static testMethod void validateHelloWorld() {
       Book__c b = new Book__c(Name='Behind the Cloud', Price__c=100);
       System.debug('Price before inserting new book: ' + b.Price__c);

       // Insert book
       insert b;

       // Retrieve the new book
       b = [SELECT Price__c FROM Book__c WHERE Id =:b.Id];
       System.debug('Price after trigger fired: ' + b.Price__c);

       // Test that the trigger correctly updated the price
       System.assertEquals(90, b.Price__c);
    }
}
```

You can take more help from [here](http://www.sfdc99.com/2013/05/14/how-to-write-a-test-class/) and [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_test.htm).